# Getting rb-inotify error "Errno::ENOSYS" with compass and susy plugin

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, sass

I have the Compass gem installed (compass-0.11.beta.2), along with the Compass susy plugin. Every time I run "compass watch", I get the error:
"Errno::ENOSYS on line ["60"] of /path/to/rb-inotify/notifier.rb: initialize inotify"
This is the block of code in notifier.rb that the error is referencing

```
def initialize
@fd = Native.inotify_init
  @watchers = {}
  return unless @fd < 0

  raise SystemCallError.new(
    "Failed to initialize inotify" +
    case FFI.errno
    when Errno::EMFILE::Errno; ": the user limit on the total number of inotify instances has been reached."
    when Errno::ENFILE::Errno; ": the system limit on the total number of file descriptors has been reached."
    when Errno::ENOMEM::Errno; ": insufficient kernel memory is available."
    else; ""
    end,
This is line ["60"] ===>  FFI.errno)
end
```

I've tried reinstalling all of the gems involved, as well as 3-4 different versions of each, but I still get the same error every time. Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your system.

The underlying call to `inotify_init(2)` is returning ENOSYS, which means that the functionality is not implemented in your system's libc, and perhaps not even supported in the kernel.

(Some old versions of Fedora Linux, for example, appear to have supported the `inotify` facility in the kernel but did not ship a glibc that exposed the feature.)

Comment: @werm, can you verify that `inotify` is working on your system, as through the command line utilities?

Comment: it works fine in every other Compass installation on the server, just not that one for whatever reason. Still haven't figured out why.